# Using Gmaps.js with a search field

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, gmaps.js

Is there a way to use a search field to seek addresses on the [Gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) library?

Also, can I get the coordinates from this address to save on my database?

I followed the Google Maps V3 API and managed to get this result, but I'm wondering if through this javascrips library is also possible. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. For a live example, please see [link](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geocoding.html).